# How to limit docker container running time in python?

Tags: python, docker

I am still new to python. I would like to run a container with limited time (5min) and also keep the try-except in case the container failed to finish running. For example:

```py
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
try:
    # how to limit the running time to 5 min, if exceeds 5 min, kill the container anyways
    container = client.containers.run("python", detach=True, name = "python-c")
except docker.errors.APIError as err:
    cont = client.containers.get("python-c")
    cont.stop()
    print(str(err))
# if run successfully, remove the container
container.remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by **waiting for 5 minutes and then killing the process**, then write on top of the script:

import time

Then, under the **cont.stop()** code, type in time.sleep(300)

(300 seconds is 5 mins, according to a calculator.)

Comment: I mean if the container can finish/fails earlier, then the container should be killed before 5 min. It's possible the container is running for more than 5 min and that's why I would like to limit the time. time.sleep seems that it only wait for 5 min no matter the container successfully/fails runs early or not